# cloud image installation error

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, ubuntu-10.04, eucalyptus

to my college final year project we planned to setup the private cloud on the two machines.

I recently installed Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud (UEC) on two of my machines .  I was trying to install the store image through WebUI. I was able to download Ubuntu 10.04 - (i386) image but while installing, it's giving me following error: -

Command 'euca-upload-bundle' returned status code 1:
Checking bucket: image-store-1296600766
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/euca-upload-bundle", line 231, in 
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/euca-upload-bundle", line 214, in main
    bucket_instance = ensure_bucket(conn, bucket, canned_acl)
  File "/usr/bin/euca-upload-bundle", line 87, in ensure_bucket
    bucket_instance = connection.get_bucket(bucket)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/boto/s3/connection.py", line 275, in get_bucket
    rs = bucket.get_all_keys(headers, maxkeys=0)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 204, in get_all_keys
    headers=headers, query_args=s)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/boto/s3/connection.py", line 342, in make_request
    data, host, auth_path, sender)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/boto/connection.py", line 459, in make_request
    return self._mexe(method, path, data, headers, host, sender)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/boto/connection.py", line 437, in _mexe
    raise e
socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

could anyone please help me?

thank you.